# Get paired list of name and type from System.Drawing.Brushes

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, system.drawing

I want to create a list of BrushInfo which has properties of a brush name and its type from System.Drawing.Brushes.  Something like:

```
Dim brushList = GetType(Drawing.Brushes) _
                   .GetProperties.Select(Function(p) New BrushInfo With 
                        {.BrushName = p.Name, .BrushValue = GetType(p)})
```

The code above will get me the name of the brush (p.Name) but will not get me the type of the brush (i.e. System.Drawing.Brushes.AliceBlue).  How do I get the brush type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the value of the property, not the type of the property.  Instead of:

```
.BrushValue = GetType(p)
```

use:

```
.BrushValue = CType(p.GetValue(Nothing, Nothing), Brush)
```

Comment: Thanks, Rick.  That was the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Brush` type is `Brush`. The name of the `Brush` is only by virtue of it being a property of that name in `Brushes`. The `Brush` itself has no further type or name beyond `Brush`.